# How to set individual option list for selects in a formbuilder

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-formbuilder

I have a model driven form with 2 selects, 'State' and 'City'.
The models looks something as below :

```
class State{
stateID : number;
stateName : String,
cities : City[]
}
class City{
cityID : number,
cityName : String
}
```

I am populating the city option list from the selection of state as I have all the data available in State[] 'stateList'.

```
    <select formControlName="state" (onchange)="getCityNameByState($event.target.value)">
                <option *ngFor="let stateName of stateList" [value]= "stateID">
                  {{stateName}}</option>

select formControlName="city">
                  <option *ngFor="let cityName of cityList" [value]= "cityID">
              {{cityName}}</option>
```

The issue here is the cityList gets formed by the selection of state which is ok for 1 set of state & city selects. But since I have a dynamic FormBuilder here, there can be multiple sets of State & City selects.
And with every selection of State, the cityList is changed for all instead of getting populated for its corresponding State in the FormGroup.
I am thinking of dynamically generating a separate cityList for every State select individually but not sure if this is the appropriate solution.
Can someone please help here.

Comment: I cannot see the issue from your snippet. Can you post a full reproduction on StackBlitz? By the way, `(onchange)` is wrong. Should be `(change)`. In fact, it shouldn't be there at all -- since you have reactive forms, use `this.form.get('state').changes.subscribe(callback)` to get notified for changes.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović Thanks for letting me know regarding valueChanges.subscribe(). Can you please help me know how I can apply this on the 'projectName' property in the following stackblitz example :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/add-nested-formbuilder-arrays-in-a-formbuilder-group?file=app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

if you need different list, you need different variables. You can do it creating an array of arrays of cities, or creating an object that has an array of cities. An example.

You must create

```
cities:string[][]=[
   [{name:"Alabama"},{name:"Boston"}...],
   [{name:"Madrid"},{name:"Barcelona"}..]
   ....
]
//Or
cities:any={
  USA:[{name:"Alabama"},{name:"Boston"}...],
  Spain:[{name:"Madrid"},{name:"Barcelona"}..]
}
```

then the loop you do is over

```
<div *ngFor="let city of cities[index]"> 
 or 
 <div *ngFor="let city of cities[dataForm.get('country').value]>
```

**Update**

@RandomGuy, you have three different things: your form, your data that feed the form and the data of States. The data of states the data you use to create the options.

At first this data will be like

```
dataStates=[
   {stateID:"AL",name="Alaska",cities:[]},
   {stateID="CL",name="California",cities:[]}
   ...all the rest of states...
]

<select formControlName="stateID" (onchange)="getCities($event.target.value)">
    <options *ngFor="let item of dataStates" [value]="item.statedID">
       {{item.name}}
    </option>
 </select>
<select formControlName="cityID" >
  <!-the options will be dataStates.find(d=>d.stateId==myArray.get('statedID').value)-->
    <options *ngFor="let city of dataStates.find(d=>d.stateId==myArray.get('statedID').value).cities" [value]="city.cityID">{{city.name}}
       {{city.name}}
    </option>
 </select>
```

The function getCities

```
//get cities check if cities of the data exist. If not fill the cities
getCities(stateID:string)
{
   let index=this.dataStates.findIndex(p=>p.stateID==stateID)
   if (index>=0){ //Always must be index>0
       if (this.dataStates.cities.length<=0)  //is not fill yet
       {
           this.httpClient.get(url+"/"+stateID).subscribe(res=>{
                 this.dataStates[index].cities=res;
           })
       }
}
```

In this way you only search the cities of the states that are in the form (not all the cities)

Comment: Hi @Eliseo I want that in my dynamic formbuilder, changing value of 1 State should only affect its respective cityList in its formgroup & does not affect the cityList in another formgroup. This does not seem to be achievable with using (change) on State select in the html as it would lead to populate generic cityList, which would then be common for all the formgroups.
I think that valueChanges.subscribe() must be used on the selected state value to generate its corresponding cityList.

Comment: My design is something as below:
    data = {states: [{stateID: "", cities: [{cityID: "" }]}]}

I am calling setStates() in my constructor.
setStates() {
    let control = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.states;
    this.data.states.forEach(x => {
      control.push(this.fb.group({
        stateID: x.stateID,
        cities: this.setCities(x)
      }))
    })
  }

  setCities(x) {
    let arr = new FormArray([])
    x.states.forEach(y => {
      arr.push(this.fb.group({
        cityID: y.cityID,
      }))
    })
   return arr;
  }

Comment: @RandomGuy, I updated my answer. remember we have three things: the form, the data that fill the form and the data of states

Comment: @RandomGuy Can you post you answer please, How did you resolved your issue?