# How to bind ngSelect dropdowns dynamically in Angular FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm facing issue with binding list with ngSelect dropdown in Anguarl FormArray, I'm building a FormGroup with FormArray contains list of state and city dropdowns.

The state ddl will load oninit(), then when i Change state, the city ddl should load with respective data, but it should not affect the other city ddl.

[image]

The other city dropdown should not load until the respected state is selected.

I'm able to load the state initially but unable to bind city ddl on state change. Here is my code. Please have a look.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormArray,
  AbstractControl
} from "@angular/forms";
import { debounceTime } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "state-block",
  templateUrl: "./state-block.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./state-block.component.scss"]
})
export class StateBlockComponent implements OnInit {
  typeLoadName: string;
  lFormGroup: FormGroup;
  states = [1, 2, 3, 4];

  stateControl: AbstractControl;
  stateFormControls: FormGroup;

  get lFormArray(): FormArray {
    return this.lFormGroup.get("lFormArray") as FormArray;
  }

  statelist = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4"];
  citylist = [];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initControls();
  }
 
  initControls() {
    this.lFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      lFormArray: this.fb.array([])
    });
    this.states.forEach(element => {
      this.stateFormControls = this.createControls();

      const myFormArray = <FormArray>this.lFormGroup.get("lFormArray");

      this.stateFormControls.get("groupIndex").patchValue(myFormArray.length);

      this.stateFormControls.valueChanges.subscribe(data =>
        this.onValuesChanged(data)
      );

      this.lFormArray.push(this.stateFormControls);

      this.lFormArray.valueChanges.subscribe(value =>
        this.onFormArrayValueChanged(value)
      );

      const citylist = [
        "zonePeril1",
        "zonePeril2",
        "zonePeril3",
        "zonePeril4"
      ];

      const selectedStateControl = this.stateFormControls.get("state");
      selectedStateControl.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
        this.stateFormControls.get("city").value = zonePerilList;
        
      });
    });
  }
  onFormArrayValueChanged(value: any): void {
    console.log("on form array value changed", value);
  }
  onValuesChanged(data: any): void {
    console.log("on value changed", data);
    
  }
  createControls() {
    return this.fb.group({
      groupIndex: "",
      state: "",
      city: "",
      
    });
  }
  
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="lFormGroup">
  <div [formGroup]="lFormGroup">
    <div formArrayName="lFormArray">
      <div
        [formGroupName]="i"
        *ngFor="let item of lFormArray.controls; let i = index"
      >
        <div class="form-group row mb-2">
          <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" for="cityId">State</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ng-select
              [items]="statelist"
              bindLabel="name"
              placeholder="Select state"
              formControlName="state"                         
            >
            </ng-select>
          </div>
          <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label" for="cityId">City</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <ng-select
              [items]="citylist"
              bindLabel="name"
              placeholder="Select city"
              formControlName="city"
            >
            </ng-select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

[This is not answered yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52574582/how-to-set-individual-option-list-for-selects-in-a-formbuilder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check stackblitz example is this what you want?

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-egj2ht

Comment: Thanks for your response, Actually When we select State, the city list must be different with others, like State1 will have different cities, and State2 will have different cities.. I have tried this code.. Please suggest is there any other approach we can achieve this..

statelist = [{name : "state1", cities :["c1","c2"]}, {name :"state2" , cities :["c3","c4"]},{name :"state3", cities :["c3","c4"]}, {name :"state4", cities :["c5","c6"]}];

 <ng-select [items]="lFormArray.get([i, 'state']).value.cities" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Select city" formControlName="city">
      </ng-select>

Comment: Hello, 
you can have additional cities_list in each formGroup
and set the cities list into that property like this
Please check the stackblitz example 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-egj2ht?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi Ashot, I have revisited you stackblitz, and seems it updated, :( , Actually I'm facing issue with dropdown, which is binded already is gone when load another dropdowns. Kindly suggest.

Comment: Hi @Cegone sorry I will fix it after 30 minute, I accidentally ruined the working exampel

Comment: @Cegone Please Can you check one more time. I have fixed it. Thanks and sorry one more time.

Comment: Yes, Working Perfect, Please keep this as it is, In Future someone can use this. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Ashot, Can you please help me on this question? 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75500864/how-to-use-pipe-in-angular-14-reactive-forms