# How to use Pipe in Angular 14 Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-pipe

We are using Angular Reactive Forms and pipes to format the data, which was working fine with Angular 9, but after upgrade to 14. Can't we use pipe in Angular Reactive Forms anymore?

The expectation is, If the user enters value like 123.45678, we need to round off and suffix with '%' symbol, like 123.457%

When the user tries to edit again (on focus), need to show the database value like 123.45678
on the blur or tab out, need to convert again like 123.457%

This scenario was working fine with Angular 9 but after upgraded to 14.

I've made sample in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw9cit).

Comment: the only issue in your example, is the `[formControlName]` applied to the readonly input, if you remove it, everything will work as expected. Here is the fixed example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw9cit-tzfkdc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hi Ashot, Thank you so much for your help, It is working as expected, you really saved my life. I assume we are in touch :)

Comment: Hi GRD, Thanks for your help, If you observe, the formControl value is getting changed with formatted value, that should not be happen. I really appreciate your effort and help. Thank you.

Comment: Hello @Cegone no problem, yeah, let me know if any questions :)

Comment: @Cegone Hi, Thanks for letting me know about the solution. Here I am giving you solution using directive. So there is not any need to use pipe at all. Your html remains the simple. Here is demo and discuss further and with all my contact details are in this demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw9cit-gwv7rg?file=package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the fake read-only component make not linked with formControl
So, remove formControlName param from the second input(read only).

And the second advice is you can delete setting value from the first input

```
 [value]="loanFormGroup.get('interest')?.value"
```

because it doesn't affect on reactive control

Demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aw9cit-fkxxdu?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Hi Nikita, Thank you so much for your help, yours and Ashot solutions are working as expected. Much appreciated your help and effort. Thanks Again.

Answer (score 0):

Nikita, Great work.  One thing I noticed is that the focus after clicking back into the edit field needs to be clicked twice.  I used your code as a starting point, but added a view child to access the field after toggling the view and then setting the focus.

```
@ViewChild("maskedInput") maskedInput : ElementRef | undefined;
```

```
toggleToUnMaskedMode(state: boolean) {
    this.editMode = state;
    setTimeout(() => {
        state ? this.maskedInput?.nativeElement.focus() : null;
    }, 0);
}
```

I also realized that you didn't need a form value to manage the state of the inputs so I just used a property to track that state.

```
editMode: boolean = true;
```

instead of (in your stackblitz example):

```
editInterest: new FormControl(false),
```